# The moment datepicker is not shown with the selected date (month) in datepicker

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I wrapped momentjs datepicker into angularjs directive.
My question is
The datepicker is not shown with the selected date (month) in datepicker.

For example, I selected 05/05/2014; 
After I hit submit button, I expand the input to get the datepicker, the current page is March not May (I am sure I update ng-model with the selected month).
Yes, I can navigate to May, and 05/05/2014 is selected.

What I want, the expanded datepicker should be May month page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just use options in datePicker which "startViewDate"